# What is exactly is a continuous curve in a Lorentzian manifold?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory, general-relativity

Often, a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$ from the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ to a metric space $M$ is called continuous at $r \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta <0$ such that for all $r' \in [r+\delta, r-\delta]$, the metric distance $d(f(r), f(r'))$ between $f(r)$ and $f(r')$ satisfies $d(f(r), f(r'))< \epsilon$. That is, arbitrarily small changes in the output of a function can be obtained from sufficiently small changes to its input.

But for me, that doesn't feel like the right definition if we are dealing with a Lorentzian manifold. For example, suppose I fire a pulse of light at point $p$ on earth, and you receive it at point $q$ on mars. Since a null curve connects $p$ and $q$, the metric distance between them is 0. Nevertheless, it seems that a curve that hops straight from $p$ to $q$ should not be called continuous, since it "jumps over" so many points in the manifold. Is my intuition wrong? Or should we perhaps be requiring that arbitrarily small changes to the **coordinates** of the curve in a given reference frame (rather than the metric distance between two points) can be obtained by arbitrarily small changes to the parameter?

Both specific answers and suggestions of good references that deal specifically and carefully with curves in Lorentzian manifolds would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: The topology has nothing to do with the Lorentz metric.  Metrics on manifolds are not the same as distance on a metric space.  A manifold by definition has an atlas of maps giving local coordinates from patches on it to $R^n$ (in this case $n=4$).  These maps induce a topology on the manifold, and all topological notions such as continuity are defined via this topology.  A manifold does not have to have a metric at all, and still has a topology.

Comment: I think the trouble here is that a "Lorentzian metric" is not a metric in the sense of metric spaces, so you cannot use it to define continuity. This is because with a Lorentzian metric two points in space-time can have negative distance. This is not allowed for a topological metric.

Comment: A terminological suggestion: Do not use the word "metric" for a  "Lorentzian metric", call it, for instance, "Lorentzian metric tensor." Reserve the word "metric" for a distance function on a set. This might help you to clear the current confusion. Also, I suggest doing some reading on general topology and the notion of an abstract manifold. After that you will realize that metric notions are not needed to define manifolds and continuity.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you all. One follow up question: if we have to use topology instead of the metric to define continuity, how do we know which topology use? For example, would we get a different class of "continuous" curves depending on whether we chose the manifold topology or the Alexandrov topology?